# Change network bonding parameters without reboot

Tags: networking, network-bonding

In Ubuntu 18.04 I have the netplan bonding configuration like this:

```
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        primary: eno1
```

I discovered that this does not actually cause the network to fail over to eno2 if the cable is unplugged from eno1 unless I set `mii-monitor-interval`, like this:

```
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      parameters:
        mode: active-backup
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

(Setting `primary` seems to be unnecessary - is it?)

However, this change does not seem to take effect after `netplan apply` - `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0` does not show the new MII Polling Interval value until I reboot.

Is there a way to apply this change without rebooting?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148838/reset-ethernet-bonding-without-rebooting suggests `service network restart` but there is no "network" service in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 4):

I found a Launch bug about this, which mentions the workaround: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nplan/+bug/1746419

Running the following as root does the trick, though this still briefly disconnects the machine from the network

```
ip link del dev bond0 && netplan apply
```

(I would advise against running the above if you only have network access to the machine!)

Comment: you saved my life.

Comment: In April 2022, this is still the only method that worked for me on Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Don't run this command remotely or it's going to be a trip to the datacenter...